# How to display image in gridview from server floder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get error following code

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Attachment/<%#Eval("Image") %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

error
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

First Try this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl(String.Format("~/Attachment/{0}",Eval("Image"))) %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

There is another option to do that in the server not in the client. its is useful if you need to set the image url in run time.

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvActivities" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnSorting="gvActivities_Sorting"
        OnRowDataBound="gvActivities_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Image' HeaderStyle-Width="4%"
                SortExpression="ActivityType">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="ImageType" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Has you can see, i am using the OnRowDataBound to set the image url.

1. I am not setting the ImageURL in the client.
2. I am checking if the Row type is a Data Row.
3. Then i am creating an image and putting the image from the grin into it. see that i am using the FindControl method. the "ImageType" is the id of the image in the grid.
4. then i am setting the imageURL Property

   ```
   protected void gvActivities_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
          Image img = (Image)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ImageType");
          img.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveClientUrl("Image URL path);
          img.AlternateText = "Text";
          img.ToolTip = "Tooltip";
       }
   }
   ```