# Server tag not well formed on asp:image of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, imageurl

confused on if I should use Eval or Bind.  I read a lot of answers on this subject and none seem to be my specific situation.  The answer on this link was suppose to work, but did not

[How to display image in gridview from server floder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638205/how-to-display-image-in-gridview-from-server-floder)

This is what I initially tried, and I do not get an error, but I do not get the picture to show up in grid.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Image" HeaderStyle-Width="250" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imagePreview"  Width="200" ImageUrl='~/ProductImages/ <%# Bind("Filename") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

then I tried re coding my asp:image tag to the following per the suggestion in the link above

`<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imagePreview"  Width="200" ImageUrl="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl(String.Format("~/ProductImages/{0}",Eval("Filename"))) %>" />`

But this gives me a

> "server tag not well formed"

error.

i also tried the suggestion of using the  tag instead but could not get that approach to work either.

Is it possible to do this without setting the image url in the code behind file and with the asp:image tag or do I have to use the img tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass image url lyk this....

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/ProductImages/"+Eval("Filename").ToString() %>'
```

Comment: This worked great.  I am loving this place too.  I send good karma your way.